# Energy-momentum tensor non-minimal scalar field

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

If we consider a non-minimal coupling term between gravity and scalar field for inflation, we can have some modifications for density and pressure of scalar field. I have some problems to obtain the form of pressure in this case. The shape of density and pressure are as the equations 4.4 and 4.5 in paper with arxiv number: gr-qc/0002091. Is there anyone to present calculations in deatils?.

Comment: What happened to the equations previously in the post (v2)?

Answer (score 1):

I'll go to answer you quickly, first, you need to calculate the stress-energy tensor of the dust/fluid perfect and the Einstein tensor with the metric in 4.1. Then you should equal component to component and isolate the density and pressure. It's easy because you can use Maple or any math program to do it.

By the way, you should use the Einstein equations with scalar field!

Good Luck!

Comment: I know the strategy completely. But i need to have the calculation in details. Do you know any reference to present it in paticular the form of pressure?

Comment: In other words, i have driven both equations density and pressure completely. But for the equation 4.5 for pressure i have obtained -6\xi\H\phi\phidot, but the equation has -4 NOT -6. I don not why i obtained this?

Comment: Well, I have a Maple archive where I calculate something similar, I can give you the archive and you can modificate to your metric.